# .htaccess seemingly ignored on OpenShift

Tags: python, django, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, openshift

I'm working on a site on OpenShift (Django, Python 2.7, Apache), and I'd like it to always be served over HTTPS. I figured this would be a simple task using `.htaccess`, and OpenShift's knowledge base [seems to show that it should be](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202398810-How-to-redirect-traffic-to-HTTPS-). However, I've been agonizing over this for days, and I can't figure out how to make it work. Basically, I can't get my `.htaccess` files to operate on anything but static files. I simply can't get requests for non-static resources to redirect to *anything*.

Here's my directory structure, inside `~/app-root/repo`. It's using the "new" (March 2014 or so?) OpenShift directory structure.

```
/MyProject
    settings.py
    urls.py
    [etc.]
/[app directories]
/static
/wsgi
    wsgi.py
    static -> ../static
manage.py
requirements.txt
```

Ok, so after much frustration, I've been testing with a minimum viable `.htaccess` to just see if I can get anything to work. It looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* http://www.google.com
```

Everything should go to Google. If I put this in the `wsgi` directory, all my static files get redirected to google.com, but nothing else does. If I put it in `~/app-root/repo`, nothing at all happens. It's like the file doesn't exist.

Similarly, if I use the commands suggested by OpenShift and put the file in `wsgi`, my static files get redirected to use HTTPS, but nothing else does.

I've also tried WSGI and Django things like adding `os.environ['HTTPS'] = "on"` to `wsgi.py` as suggested by [sites like this one](http://www.pdxpixel.com/blog/setting-up-django-site-ssl-apache-mod_wsgi-mod_ssl/). That's been ineffective, and I really can't say I'm knowledgable enough about those sorts of settings to know what I'd need to add, but ideally I'd like to do this through `.htaccess`. The request should be using SSL before it hits WSGI.

What do I need to do to make my `.htaccess` files work on *all* requests? And why is OpenShift ignoring `.htaccess` files not in `wsgi`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fought with this for a short time and quickly decided to use the django-ssl-redirect middleware package.

The whole reason I'm on OpenShift is to avoid fighting with these kinds of configuration issue, so I'm a little disappointed I had to resort to this.

Still, here goes:

Just add this to your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES

```
'ssl_redirect.middleware.SSLRedirectMiddleware',
```

Add this to requirements.txt

```
django-ssl-redirect==1.0
```

Add something like this in settings (I put this in my base settings file that I share in multiple environments, hence the "if").

```
if os.environ.has_key('OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'):
    SSL_ON = True
    SSL_ALWAYS = True
```

More info here: https://bitbucket.org/nextscreenlabs/django-ssl-redirect

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm on OpenShift too. Everything has been super easy, except for this! The SSL redirect middleware does seem to work, so I'll settle for that. Thanks!